# Encoding special characters in URLs with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following Ruby code snippet:

```
  url = "http://somewiki.com/index.php?book=#{author}:#{title}&action=edit"
  encoded = URI.encode(url)
  encoded.gsub(/&/, "%26").sub(/%26action/, "&action")
```

The last line is needed since I have to encode the ampersands (`&`) in the author and title but I need to leave the last one (`&action...`) intact.

Consider this example for clarity:

```
author = "John & Diane"
title = "Our Life & Work"
url = "http://somewiki.com/index.php?book=#{author}:#{title}&action=edit"
encoded = URI.encode(url)
encoded.gsub(/&/, "%26").sub(/%26action/, "&action")

# => "http://somewiki.com/index.php?book=John%20%26%20Diane:Our%20Life%20%26%20Work&action=edit"
```

Although this result is satisfactory, I'd like to clean the original code with the `gsub/sub` calls. Any ideas?

PS: I could "clean" both params before passing them to the `url = ...` line but then the `%` characters will be re-encoded as `%25` by the `URI.encode` call so I don't think that's an option. I'd love to be proved wrong here though.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36191180/520567 , you can use a specified parser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you need the unencoded url (for logging?), I would just:

```
encoded_url = "http://somewiki.com/index.php?book=#{CGI.escape(author)}:#{CGI.escape(title)}&action=edit"
```

Comment: `URI.encode` does not encode & as %26.

Comment: Correct, I meant CGI.escape().  I should review my review next time